# ¿Cómo hago para abrir un archivo y extraer su texto y mostrarlo en un tkinter.Text()?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un editor de código, y quiero que se pueda abrir un archivo (de lo que sea... `.txt`/`.py`/`.js`/`.c`, etc...) y mostrarlo en el `Text` que tengo para poder escribir en él.

Tengo un `tk.Text()` donde el usuario escribe su código, y también unos botones para guardar en `.py`/`.js`/`.txt`/`.c`, lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el texto extraído del archivo importado en el texto para que se pueda editar.

Dejo el código de la función que hice (se llama desde un botón llamado "Abrir") (el texto se llama `mesnajeTxt`, lo aprendí gracias a un tutorial y lo escribí mal xD):

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def open_file():
file = filedialog.askopenfile(title="Abir...")
mesnajeTxt = file
```

Lo que haría esto es hacer una variable "file" que le pida al usuario abrir un archivo mediante el filedialog, y luego, la variable "mesnajeTxt", que representa el texto del código, sería igual a `file`, pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas si he entendido bien, lo que necesitas es que dentro de tu interfaz tienes un Text() y quieres mediante un boton capturar el contenido de un fichero y sobre la interfaz poder modificarlo y con otro boton guardar los cambios en el fichero. si es así espero que te sirva, he creado una interfaz con un Text() y dos botones uno que captura el texto y otro para guardar los cambios si quieres modificarlo a través de la interfaz. Espero te sirva para lo que estas buscando. Un saludo

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import io
from io import open
# creo funcion que lee el archivo lo guarda en una variable y lo introduce dentro del text()
def atrapa_texto():
    f = open ('fichero_prueba.txt','r')
    mensaje = f.read()
    print(mensaje)
    f.close()
    texto.insert(1.0,mensaje)
# con esta funcion modificamos el texto desde el text() de la interfaz
def modifica_texto():
    f = open ('fichero_prueba.txt','a')
    f.write(texto.get(1.0,END))
    f.close()


#creamos la interfaz con un text() y un boton para introducir el texto llamando a la funcion anterior    
raiz=Tk()
nombre_usuario="Prueba para Foro"
raiz.geometry("700x500+0+0")
raiz.title(nombre_usuario)
etiqueta_comentario=Label(raiz,text="TEXTOS").place(x=10, y=20)
texto = Text(raiz)
texto.place(x=30, y=45)
boton10=Button(raiz,text="Capturar TEXTO",command=atrapa_texto).place(x=150,y=20)
boton10=Button(raiz,text="Modificar TEXTO",command=modifica_texto).place(x=250,y=20)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Te debo una, me has salvado, funciona a la perfeccion :D